# Is it possible to create a copy-on-write copy of a file on an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, hfs+

I need to copy a file that will be modified later on an iOS device. For performance reasons, it would be great if this would work copy-on-write, i.e. the file is not really duplicated, and only modified blocks of the copy are written later.

As pointed out in the comments, this probably has to be supported by the file system (HFS+?). A link is not sufficient, since both the old (A) and new (B) file name will point to the same file, and if I modify A, B will also change.

A "lazy" copy also would not help, since on first write the whole file would still need to be copied.

I was thinking more about a solution like the one described by @Hot Licks that would start with A and B using the same blocks on disk, and when I write to file B, only the modified blocks would be stored on disk, while identical parts in A and B go on using the same blocks on disk.

Is this possible on iOS?

Regards,
Jochen

Comment: I don't undestand what are you need, just the one file in different pathes? If that try to use hardlinks (NSFileManager's method - (BOOL)linkItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error).

Comment: @aknew - "Copy on write" is, I think, a UNIXism.  Basically, you say that you're copying the file, and the "new" file "appears" in its directory, but really the file pointer is pointing to the old file.  Then, if you write to the file, a new copy is actually made, in some cases on a sector-by-sector basis so that unchanged sectors are "shared" with the original.  Various memory-mapping tricks may be used to accomplish this.  Berkley Unix and, I think, some of the VAX OSes did this to one degree or another.  Don't know about Linux.

Comment: Jochen -- I've never heard of this being available on iOS, but maybe you could dummy it up with something like what @Petesh proposes.

Comment: @Hot Licks  - first part (pointer to old file instead copy) just is hard link, but i don't now how to implement create real copy on write to new file (pointer). I think, it show be implement in file system. P.S. I would look for keywords "lazy copy", not for "copy on write", but I'm still not sure I understand Jochen correctly

Comment: I like to learn about new design/new ways of doing things. I am just curious of what is the advantage of **copy-on-write** in an application on a mobile device running in a sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in mechanism for doing efficient partial copies of files, but if you're copying a file and making internal changes to the content, then the most efficient mechanism to use is mmap. You map the file into memory and modify it in-place. The changes are written back to the file automatically without needing to rewrite the file in pieces.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

struct stat astat;
int fd = open("filename", O_RDWR);
if ((fd != -1) && (fstat(fd, &astat) != -1)) {
    char *data = mmap(0, astat.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (data != MAP_FAILED) {
        self.data_ptr = data;
        self.data_size = astat.st_size;
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

When you're done with the file, you use munmap to release the mapping back to the os:

```
munmap(self.data_ptr, self.data_size);
```

The usual caveats apply from modifying a shared resource.